# Find all male User with specific Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Lets say I have a Moder `User` that has many `Posts`.

So now for example I choose the `Users` who are male:

```
User.where(gender: male)
```

How can I extend my search query and select only the male User who have a `Post` with a tagging `[sport,holiday]`?

If I only had to use `Posts` I would simply call:

```
Post.where(tag: [sport,holiday])
```

How can I connect these two queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) should work:

```
User.joins(:posts).where(gender: male, posts: { tag: [sport, holiday] })
```

`uniq` makes your query `DISTICT`:

```
User.joins(:posts).where(gender: male, posts: { tag: [sport, holiday] }).uniq
```

alternatively:

```
User.includes(:posts).where(gender: male, posts: { tag: [sport, holiday] })
```

Comment: Sorry but your code returns the same User several times if he has several posts with the tags sport or holiday

Comment: @JohnSmith updated my answer, inspect the resulting SQL query to find the most appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have the associations set up correctly (`user` `has_many` `posts`), you may want to use a combination of `scopes` and `associations` to do it:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts do
      def tagged tags
         where tag: tags
      end
   end

   scope :male, -> { where(gender: male) }
end

#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This would allow you to call:

```
users = User.male # -> returns collection
users.each do |user|
    user.posts.tagged([sport, holiday]) #-> returns collection of posts with tags
end
```

---

**Update**

To do it the other way, you can probably use the following:

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   scope :tagged, ->(tags)   { where(tag: tags) }
   scope :gender, ->(gender) { joins(:user).where(gender: gender) }
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
end
```

** In process of testing the `joins` scope - not sure if that will work

--

This will allow you to call (thanks to [scope chaining](http://blog.envylabs.com/post/52395695243/chaining-scopes-in-rails-4)):

```
tagged_posts = Post.tagged([sport,holiday]).gender(male)
```

Comment: i think there was an misunderstanment, i would like to have returned the users not the posts! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
@users = Post.where(tag: [sport,holiday]).users.where(gender: male)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct it would be to call:

```
User.joins(:posts).where(gender: male, posts: { tag: [sport, holiday] }).uniq
```

So that the Users get selected only once